# Find the equation of the plane that contains the point $Q(1,2,5)$ and is parallel to the plane $2x-z= 1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, plane-geometry

How would I start this, I know that the normal vector is $\left<2,0,-1\right>$ and the dot product of the normal and the point $Q$ is $-3$.

Comment: If you know a point and the normal vector, you literally just plug it into the standard form.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need the dot product or vector product. You know, because the two planes have to be parallel, that the second plane has as equation:

2x - z = d.

Filling in the given point Q and solving for d yields the answer.